# For Golang, is context.Context passed by reference, or do I need to return it at the end of my function?

Tags: go

Given this example:

```
func A(ctx context.Context){
    
    // Do some work
    ctx = context.WithValue(ctx, "key", "value")
}

func B(ctx context.Context){
    
    // Requires value of key
    ctx = context.Value("key")
}

func main() {
    ctx := context.Background()
    A(ctx)
    B(ctx)
}
```

How does function B, which takes in ctx, have the updated ctx with "key" : "value"? I understand it will not have the updated context because we passed the context by value (proven after testing quickly in Go Playground), hence it is not mutated.

In this case, should I be returning the context from A as well (Is this the proper practice of using context)? The reason why I'm having functions A and B instead of chucking everything in `main` is because those functions contain reused logic. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Given that there simply _is_ no "pass-by-reference" in Go and everything is always passed by value (and the fact that Context API is designed and the documentation for it) this was clear: Yes, you must return the new context. And you should think about what you do with the old context, e.g. if this carries not only values but cancelation. Whether this is good design is a matter of taste.

Comment: I see, thanks for the response! This is because I was refactoring some developer's code where everything was cramped into one function so I'm trying to abstract this out into various smaller functions but encountered this issue. I will clarify about the usage of the values with context, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`context.WithValue` creates a new child context whose parent if the one given as parameter. The context given as parameter to your function B won't hold the needed key. You can indeed return the new context from A and then give it to B as parameter.